# How to get a commands history from Firebird server

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

is there any possibility to receive a commands history from firebird server? I have seen something similar in other engines, commited commands were saved in txt file.

Comment: @AbhijitKumbhar How can a question about Firebird be a duplicate of a question about SQL Server?

Comment: because when you asked that question it is about SQL Server, But you edited that to #Firebird and I posted to duplicate for your previous #SQL SERVER. That's not wrong :) and After your edit this is not duplicate !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what youre looking for is Firebirds [Trace and Audit Services](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes254.html#rnfb25-trace):

> The new trace and audit facilities enable various events performed inside the engine, such as statement execution, connections, disconnections, etc., to be logged and collated for real-time analysis of the corresponding performance characteristics.
>
> A trace takes place in the context of a trace session. Each trace session has its own configuration, state and output.
>
> The Firebird engine has a fixed list of events it can trace. It can perform two different sort of traces: a system audit and a user trace. How the engine forms the list of events for a session depends on which sort of trace is requested.

Comment: I have found some better solution
http://ibsurgeon.com/fbscanner-firebird-scanner/
 It's not free, but trial show all the selects.